# C++11 implicitly convert

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

```
#include <string>

struct String
{
    template<typename T> operator T*() { return 0; }
    operator std::string() { return ""; }
};

int main()
{
    String myStr;

    std::string str1(myStr); // ambiguous, error C2668

    std::string str2 = myStr; // error C2440:
    // 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'String' to
    // `std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>',
    // No constructor could take the source type,
    // or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

    const std::string& rStr = myStr; // Ok, but why?
}
```

I'm using VS 2013.

Questions:

1. Why do the definitions of `str1` and `str2` lead to different compile errors?
2. As I know, when `rStr` is created, a temporary string object is created firstly, then `rStr` will refer to the temporary. But, why does the creation of the temporary object not lead a compile error? Is there any different between `tmp` and `strN`?

Comment: For all I can tell, the second error is a bug. g++ and clang++ accept the definition+initialization of `str2`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first definition, `std::string str1(myStr);` is indeed ambigous:

```
std::string str1(myStr.operator char*());
// or
std::string str1(myStr.operator std::string());
```

so this initialization fails due to an ambiguity.

This is essentially the same scenario as

```
void foo(char const*);
void foo(std::string);

foo(myStr); // ambiguous
```

Exactly one user-defined conversion is required, then a function will be called (for the first definition, the function is a constructor). Both conversions are viable, and neither is a subset of the other, so both have the same rank.

---

The second definition, `std::string str2 = myStr;` is actually *fine*. Only one user-defined conversion *to* `std::string` is allowed, either via a constructor or via a conversion function, not both. So only `std::string str2 = myStr.operator std::string();` is viable.

Note `string str2 = expr;` when `expr` is not of type `string` requires the `expr` to be *converted to `std::string`*. The resulting temporary is then used to initialize `str2` via a copy/move:

```
string str2 = string(expr);
//            ~~~~~~ implicit
```

Therefore, the conversion on the right hand side *must convert directly* to `std::string`, otherwise you would need a chain of two user-defined conversions to initialize the temporary: (UDC = User-Defined Conversion)

```
string str2 = string(expr);
// resolved as:
string str2 = expr.operator string();        // fine: one implicit UDC
string str2 = string(expr.operator char*()); // error: two UDCs
```

For example, `expr` to `char const*` via the `operator char*` and then to a `std::string` via the converting constructor requires a chain of two user-defined conversions => not viable. If we try to use the `operator char*()` conversion, we need an additional constructor *implicit* constructor call to make the RHS a `string`.

This is different from `string str1( expr )`, where `expr` does not need to be converted *implicitly* to `string`. It *might* have to be converted to initialize a parameter of a string constructor. The direct initialization of `str1` from the *possibly converted* `expr` is not a(n implicit) conversion itself, but just a function call. No extra temporary is created:

```
string str1( expr );
// resolved as:
string str1( expr.operator string() ); // fine
string str1( expr.operator char* () ); // fine
```

This second definition is refused when compiling *with* enabled language extension. Without language extensions, this initialization is fine in VS2013 Update 2.

---

The third one follows a different initialization scheme. It should behave like the second one in this case, as far as I can tell. The language extensions seems to apply only to the second one but not to the third one, it seems.

Comment: *Maybe* the behaviour of the extension is related [to this behaviour when assigning to a `std::string`](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/743685/std-string-assignment-should-probably-be-ambiguous-and-fail-to-compile-but-is-not).

Comment: Why the ambiguity in the first case, isn't the non-template function preferred thus avoiding the instantiation of the templated operator?

Comment: @icepack The non-template vs. template disambiguation only applies to selecting a target function, not to conversions AFAICT. Both (all three, copy+move) viable constructors are non-templates.

Comment: The second definition,Is there something like this,std::string str2(myStr->operator char*) or std::string str2(myStr->operator std::string);

Comment: @LeonhartSquall Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. I replaced the lax syntax I used to show which conversions are performed with possible less ambiguous function call. The second definition is functionally equivalent to `std::string str2( myStr.operator std::string() );`. That is, a temporary `std::string` is constructed as the return value of the conversion function; this temporary is then moved to `str2`.

Comment: As I know,Compiler will apply only one user-defined conversion at a time.In the first case.And in initializations, the initializer converted to the type of the variable is implicit conversion.So For std::string str1(myStr.operator char*()) why can not I think will lead twice implicit conversion?So,only std::string str1(myStr.operator std::string()) is right,in the first case.Exactly i can not understand the different between std::string str1(myStr) and std::string str2 = myStr, i think they are both initializer.

Comment: @LeonhartSquall Explicit construction is not a conversion. A conversion includes constructing a temporary. You could as well have an overload set like `void foo(char const*); void foo(std::string); foo(myStr);` which has the same problem. For the second one, it's important to note that `=` and `()` for initialization behave differently. Using parentheses is *direct-initialization* (a constructor function will be called directly) whereas `=` is *copy-initialization* (a temporary will be created and copied/moved).